# How to get data between connecting web part in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

are there any ways that in the eventreceiver of one of the two connected lists, i can get the filter value between 2 connected list web parts.

BR 
Kelvin

Answer (score 0):

Event receiver will not help you as it triggers item related events like create, update, delete. Event receiver cannot reach data sent from one webpart to another. You can create your own webpart that can receive data and connect it to task webpart same way as webpart with document library. I created webpart that can get data from another webpart via data connection. You can find it here including sources: https://spgooglemappart.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks Jan. My issue has 2 parts. 1, get data from filter,2 update the document library column when new document is uploaded. Your thoughts about get data is great, but how can I do update without using eventreciever?